# using Lattice Isomorphism Theorem toto find all subgroups $\left\{H | \:SL_n\left(F_7\right)\le H\le GL_n\left(F_7\right)\right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am desperately trying to use the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem to find all subgroups $\left\{H | \:SL_n\left(F_7\right)\le H\le GL_n\left(F_7\right)\right\}$,
(where $F_7$ is the prime field of 7 elements).
But I just don't understand how.

I noticed $SL_n\left(F_7\right)$ is normal in $GL_n\left(F_7\right)$, and so, exists an isomorphism $\phi(H)=H/SL_n(F_7)$... But I have no idea what to do with it.

I would appreciate your help in solving it(spent lots of time on it...)
thanks

Comment: The Lattice Theorem gives a correspondence between those subgroups $H$ and all the subgroups of $GL_n(F_7)/SL_n(F_7)$. Try to find all the subgroups of $GL_n(F_7)/SL_n(F_7)$ and use the isomorphism to get the desired subgroups in the other level.